# Find the relations between two parameters

Tags: equation-solving, functions

```
v = 0.1;
v^2 a1^4 + (1 - v0^2) a1^2 - 2 w v0 a1 - w^2 == 0;
v^2 a2^4 + (1 - v0^2) a2^2 - 2 w v0 a2 - w^2 == 0;
v^2 a3^4 + (1 - v0^2) a3^2 - 2 w v0 a3 - w^2 == 0;
v^2 a4^4 + (1 - v0^2) a4^2 - 2 w v0 a4 - w^2 == 0;
(Exp[I (a1 + a2)] + Exp[I (a3 + a4)]) (a1^2 - a2^2) (a3^2 - 
  a4^2) + (Exp[I (a1 + a3)] + Exp[I (a2 + a4)]) (a2^2 - 
  a4^2) (a3^2 - a1^2) + (Exp[I (a2 + a3)] + 
  Exp[I (a1 + a4)]) (a1^2 - a4^2) (a2^2 - a3^2) == 0;
```

The paper tell me that the above equations are simultaneously solved numerically to find the relations between v0(In figure,v0 is $v_0$) and w(In figure,w is $\omega_1$) by root-finding algorithm.But now,I still not know how to get the relations between v0 and w through Mathematica.Could you please help me know how to get the relations through Mathematica?Thanks.

**Edit:**
 Now,I have transformed the above equations

```
    v = 0.1;
    v^2 a1^4 + (1 - v0^2) a1^2 - 2 w v0 a1 - w^2 == 0;
    v^2 a2^4 + (1 - v0^2) a2^2 - 2 w v0 a2 - w^2 == 0;
    v^2 a3^4 + (1 - v0^2) a3^2 - 2 w v0 a3 - w^2 == 0;
    v^2 a4^4 + (1 - v0^2) a4^2 - 2 w v0 a4 - w^2 == 0;
    (Exp[I (a1 + a2)] + Exp[I (a3 + a4)]) (a1^2 - a2^2) (a3^2 - 
    a4^2) + (Exp[I (a1 + a3)] + Exp[I (a2 + a4)]) (a2^2 - 
    a4^2) (a3^2 - a1^2) + (Exp[I (a2 + a3)] + 
    Exp[I (a1 + a4)]) (a1^2 - a4^2) (a2^2 - a3^2) == 0;
```

into equations

```
v = 0.1;
p^2 - q^2 + 2*c^2 == (v0^2 - 1)/v^2;
(p^2 - c^2)*(q^2 - c^2) == -w^2/v^2;
c*(p^2 + q^2) == (w*v0)/v^2;
8*p^2*c^2*Sin[p]*Sinh[q] - p^4*Sin[p]*Sinh[q] + 16*p*q*c^2*Cos[2*c] - 
16*p*q*c^2*Cos[p]*Cosh[q] - 8*q^2*c^2*Sin[p]*Sinh[q] - 
4*p^2*q^2*Sin[p]*Sinh[q] - 2*q^4*Sin[p]*Sinh[q] == 0;
```

So,we can get v0-w through these equations.In fact,a v0 to two w,like

[image]
[image]

Now,how to solve these equations to get two v0-w.Tanks!

Comment: Try rewriting your expression without subscripts.  You may find this solves your problem.  People are more likely to try to help if you can simplify the problem before presenting it.

Comment: @mikado  Thank you for your reminding.

Comment: Using `NSolve` to solve the first four equations for $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ and plugging that solution into equation (5) gives `True`. So it should be `Reduce` or `FullSimplify` for equations (1 - 4) using those solutions, shouldn't it?

Comment: @gwr Sorry,I have tried what you said.I rewrite my question for adding a figure

Comment: who can help me?I need your several reference

Comment: I have solve this question just now.